# Javascript editable area with programmatic styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

Is there an editable textarea in javascript/html that I can search the contents of, and apply programmatic styles to? For example, whenever they type a *, indent the current line, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use either [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) or [ACE](http://ace.ajax.org/).

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) editor. These can be extended to your needs, but requires you to dive in the source-code.

Here are some useful resources:

http://wysiwygbbcode.codeplex.com/
http://md-wysiwyg.sourceforge.net/